# Run Laravel schedule every weekend

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Can anyone tell me that I need to create a schedule in Laravel 5.4 which run on every weekend automatically.

First I have created a file **FollowAdvisor.php** at `/app/Console/Commands/`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use DB;

class FollowAdvisor extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'follow:advisor';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
        DB::table('followers')->delete();
        $this->info('All inactive users are deleted successfully');
    }
}
```

Then I access this file on Kernel.php located at `/api/app/Console/`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use DB;
use App\Model\Follow;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
            Commands\FollowAdvisor::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->exec('follow:advisor')->everyMinute();

    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

When I run command `php artisan follow:advisor` on command prompt.
It is working. But I want that it must be running automatically.

Thanks

Comment: "I have created a schedule" You should show us that. You should also let us know if you set up the schedule to run via a cron.

Comment: I think you could supply a lot more information, if you want a good answer.

Comment: [Take a look at the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling). If that doesn't help, please show what you have created, so we can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

1. Make sure you have a crontab running that points to the Laravel file `artisan`

   ```
   * * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
   ```
2. `->saturdays();` Is a shorthand / more expressive way than a crontab to say every saturday

Comment: Excuse me, but what do you mean by the path to the project? I mean, what should I do if I am already there?

Comment: Crontab does not from the directory it is edited from, so what I meant was the absolute path to your project

Comment: Yeah, already got that. For people who will face to face with the unknowladge, run `crontab -e` and there, at the end of the file, add this:  `* * * * * php /path/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 2):

Starting The Scheduler
When using the scheduler, you only need to add the following Cron entry to your server. If you do not know how to add Cron entries to your server

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

---

REF : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling#introduction

Answer (score 0):

After Creation of your command and shedular in laravel 5.4 please set cron in server. so your command could be run automatically.

Following is the crontab command on each minute run.

- - - - - php /path-to-your-project/artisan follow:advisor >> /dev/null 2>&1

I hope It will work for you.